# Proving every set that is bounded below has a greatest lower bound

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let us suppose that every subset of $\mathbb R$ that is bounded above has a lowest upper bound. I want to prove as a corollary from this axiom that every subset of $\mathbb R$ that is bounded below has a greatest upper bound. Here is some of the proof I've done:

"*Let $S \subset \mathbb R$ be a non-empty set that is bounded below. Let $L \subset \mathbb R$ be the set containing all lower bounds of $S$. Then for all $m \in L, m \leq s$ for all $s \in S$. Thus, by definition, all elements of $S$ are upper bounds of $L$, so $L$ is bounded above. Hence, $L$ has a least upper bound, denoted $\alpha$.*"

My question is, how do you now show that $\alpha = inf(S)$ if $\alpha = sup(L)$?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha=\sup L$, must we have$$(\forall s\in S):\alpha\leqslant s?\tag1$$Yes, because otherwise there would be a $s\in S$ such that $\alpha>s$. But then, since $\alpha=\sup L$, there must be some $l\in L$ such that $l>s$. This is impossible, since $L$ is the set of the lower bounds of $S$.

So, $(1)$ holds and therefore $\alpha$ is a lower bound of $S$. Must it be the *greatest* lower bound? Yes, because if $\beta$ is a lower bound of $S$, then, since $\alpha=\sup L$ and $\beta\in L$, $\beta\leqslant\alpha$.

Therefore, $\alpha$ is the greatest lower bound of $S$, which means that $\alpha=\inf S$.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how you got that if $\alpha = sup L$, then there would be some $l \in L$ such that $l \gt s$.

Comment: If $l\leqslant s$ for each $l\in L$, then $s$ is an upper bound of $L$ and therefore, since $\alpha$ is the *least* upper bound of $L$, $\alpha\leqslant s$. But we are assuming that $\alpha>s$.

Comment: I know you are assuming that $a \gt s$, since you're doing a contradiction. But how do you conclude that $s \lt l$ from the fact that $\alpha = sup L$?

Comment: I have answered that question in my previous comment. Do you want me to post the same answer once again?

Comment: Never mind. I see now that you were doing the contrapositive. Thanks.